# How to check for a number in a string using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string in a variable `$vreponse` and the string is

```
int.force_snmp_version  T_SIZE  3
```

All I want to do is verify if there is number 3 in the string. If the verification is success print a message or else print fail message

I have tried something like this

```
my $vresponse = $ua->get("https://$user:$pass\@$ern_ip/get_param?p=init.force_snmp_version");

if ($vresponse->decoded_content =~ /\b3$/)
{
print "SUCESS\n";
}
else
{ print "not\n"; }
```

This is not working, do I need to change `$vresponse->decoded_content` ?

Comment: This is simple string search or regex.

Comment: -1 no research effort `print ("some3text" =~ /3/);` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just

```
if ( $vresponse =~ /3/ ) { ... }
```

which just checks that there is a `3` character somewhere in the string.

Or, more precisely

```
if ( $vresponse =~ /\b3$/ ) { ... }
```

which check that the *last* character is `3` and it is alone, i.e. not the end of, say, `23`.

Comment: @mac: If the text is returned from an HTTPS request then it is unlikely to be just a single line. `/\b3$/` checks whether there is a `3` at the end of the *entire string*. To check whether there is a `3` at the end of *any line* within the string, use `/\b3$/m`. I can't help better than that wihout seeing the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $vresponse = 'int.force_snmp_version  T_SIZE  3';
my $char = '3';

my $result = index($vresponse , $char);

if ($result >=0)
{
  #display found
}
else
{
  #display not found
}
```